# Python copy specific key/value from one dictionary to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have the following two dictionaries and list:

```
locator = ['LOCATOR1']

dict1 = {
'LOCATOR1': ['18d42734-c8c6-4409-81cf-315cdc5f02c4'],
'LOCATOR2': ['8ddec8ba-4418-4cef-8cd9-72808f615502']
}

dict2 = {
'LOCATOR3': ['0c4543be-38e3-4647-bd35-b40690429233'],
}
```

What I am hoping to achieve is using my list 'locator' to find the matching key and its value from 'locator' in dict1 and copy it to dict 2, so that I have something like this:

```
dict2 = {
'LOCATOR3': ['0c4543be-38e3-4647-bd35-b40690429233'],
'LOCATOR1': ['18d42734-c8c6-4409-81cf-315cdc5f02c4']
}
```

Then I can remove LOCATOR1 from dict1.

Comment: `for key in locator: dict2[key] = dict1.pop(key)`.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Keep in mind @Guimoute's suggestion will fail with an KeyError if a key isn't found in `dict1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the update function on dict2 with a comprehension that will pop the keys from dict1:

```
dict2.update((k,dict1.pop(k)) for k in locator if k in dict1)

{'LOCATOR3': ['0c4543be-38e3-4647-bd35-b40690429233'], 
 'LOCATOR1': ['18d42734-c8c6-4409-81cf-315cdc5f02c4']}
```